# Keep Attributes attached to dataset in Pandas and Dask

Tags: python, pandas, github, repository, dask

I use Pandas and Dask all the time. I also have a number of custom classes and functions which I utilize a lot for different analyses, which I am always having to edit to account for either Dask or Pandas. I consistently find myself in a situation where I wish I could assign attributes to the dataset which I am analyzing, minimizing the `compute` command from dask and also allowing easier management of functions as I switch between data types. Something effectively akin to:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
from pydataset import data

df = data('titanic')

setattr(df, 'vals12', 1)

test = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions = 2)
test.vals12 #would still contain the attribute vals12

df  = test.compute()
df.vals12 #would still contain the attribute vals12
```

However, I do not know of a way to achieve this, without editing the base packages (Pandas / Dask). As a result, I was wondering if there was a way to achieve the above example without creating a new class (or static version of the packages) or if there is a way to "branch" the repos in a non-public way (allowing for my edits to be added, but still allowing me to easily get future features without pain)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the upcoming release of Dask, you will be able to do this by using the recent `attrs` feature in pandas 1.0. For now, you can pip install dask from Github to use this functionality.

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "a":[0,1,2],
    "b":[2,3,4]
})
df.attrs["vals12"] = 1

ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
ddf.attrs
{'vals12': 1}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like `attrs` is preserved after calling compute on the dask dataframe, e.g. `df2 = ddf.compute()`. That is, `df2.attrs` will be empty.